# How to "grep" in PowerShell one-liner?

Tags: regex, powershell, grep, select-string

What is the best short one-liner in PowerShell to use as a `grep` alternative?

> I wanted to share with you this short one-liner syntax for PowerShell version of `grep`, which perhaps is relatively little known.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Can you [edit] the "question" part to make it fit better in this platform? For example, the title could be "How can I do X in PowerShell".

Comment: Have to agree with @Tom here. This is not a question on its own.

Comment: Hey @TomFenech, thanks for the suggestion! I do not quite understand how the title "How can I do X in PowerShell" would make it seem as not a question since there is no option in StackOverflow question forms to differentiate questions vs. "solutions" as well.

Comment: The point is that is *should* be written in a Question/Answer format. That is, your Question should be "how can I do X?" and your Answer should be "here is how you do it".

Comment: This is covered in the Help Center here https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I revised the question, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

**# In `Bash`, one could write, for example:**

```
grep -Po '^\w+ \w+' myfile
```

to extract the first two words from a given file.

## **# This can be translated to PowerShell in the following syntax:**

```
(sls '^\w+ \w+' myfile).Matches.Value
```

where `sls` is the alias for `Select-String`. See: `Get-Alias -Definition Select-String`.

Another option:

```
(cat myfile) -match '^\w+ \w+'; $Matches.0
```

However, this one is already somewhat complex; and the first part outputs additional `True/False`, which you may want to discard.

Comment: Note there is nothing specific to `bash` about your invocation of `grep`.

Comment: Might also note the alias `cat` is short for `Get-Content`.

Comment: Also note that if `myfile` contains more than 1 line, the `-match` solution, won't work - unless you add the `-Raw` switch to `cat` (`Get-Content`) in order to read the whole file as a single string.

Comment: I didn't know about grep's -o option to only output the match.  In powershell 7, select-string highlights the match.

Comment: @chepner, yes, you are right! Can you suggest what to write instead?